# Show multiple notifications per day in android using Alarm manager

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want to show 2 notifications per day in my application in 2 specific time, until now i'm just able to show one notification.
This is my code, how can i show multiple notification.
one at 7 AM , and the other at 6 PM for example?

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Calender.this, MyAlarmService.class);
         int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Calender.this, id,
                myIntent, Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar timeToSet = Calendar.getInstance();
        timeToSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                timeToSet.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

and i called this in MyAlarmService in the onStart method

```
     final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


    Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
            getString(R.string.app_name), System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Calender.class);
    PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT);
    note.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.app_name),
            "Some String", i);
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NOTIFY_ME_ID =  System.currentTimeMillis();
    mgr.notify((int) NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);
```

Comment: Set the alarm manager twice.

Comment: Should i call all the lines of code to set the alarm again or alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                timeToSet.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent); ?

Comment: I thinks yes, define once again `timeToSet`, this time with 6PM for example, and set the `alarmManager.set(....)` for the new time.

Answer (score 0):

You should set different keys for different notifications. If you use one key for several notifications it will rewrite the same one.